# uboot kernel and dtb calculation

Tags: kernel, u-boot, device-tree

What is the method to calculate these parameters in uboot ? :

```
bootm_low=0
bootm_size=7ff00000
fdt_addr_r=0x40000000
fdt_high=0x100000
fdt_size_r=0x400000
fdtcontroladdr=7bc971c0
kernel_addr_r=0x18000000
kernel_comp_addr_r=0x30000000
kernel_comp_size=0x3C00000
kernel_size_r=0x10000000
loadaddr=0x8000000
pxefile_addr_r=0x10000000
ramdisk_addr_r=0x02100000
```

My boot command :

```
fatload mmc 0:1 $kernel_addr_r Image.gz
fatload mmc 0:1 $fdt_addr_r system.dtb
booti $kernel_addr_r - $fdt_addr_r
```

I have 4G or DRAM on an A53. My kernel has different behavior when I change one of these parameter.

I also use the `fdt_high` parameter because I can't boot my kernel without but I don't know how to calculate the right value.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
It was a RAM configuration issue.
I have 2GB, not 4GB.

I changed the memory section in device tree and I use the default address values in uboot parameters and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting all of those, and not all of them are needed just to load and boot a kernel.  See the documentation at https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/environment.html for what these mean, and look at other examples for your specific SoC to likely find reasonable defaults to use.